# Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html

Tags: vue.js

I created an default vue app and do not changed anything, but when I tried to run it, I got

[image: This:]

Comment: Did you create your app with Vue cli ?

Comment: Yes, via: npm install -g @vue/cli

Answer (score 0):

The default [since January 20, 2022](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-as-the-new-default.html) is to [use Vue3](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application) (and you should), even if you still want to use Options API because [Vue2 will be end of life](https://vuejs.org/about/faq.html#what-s-the-difference-between-vue-2-and-vue-3) next year (and is just slower/with more cons).

So make yourself a favor and start with this rather

```
npm init vue@latest
```